# What does "bureaucracy" refer to in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://youtu.be/EctE3dEAwEY?t=1m15s

> These zones(Jebel Ali Free zone) attract businesses with tax breaks, custom duty benefits, and no foreign ownership restrictions, all within a developed infrastructure, that is run by an independent authority, **helping streamlined bureaucracy.**

Does "helping streamlined bureaucracy" mean "attracting lots of bussinesses ultimately benefit the **Dubai authority?** **Dubai's** efficient, streamlined **bureaucracy?**

Or does it mean **this Free Zones** were able to run streamlined businessess?

Comment: I think there's a typo/OCR error there. It should probably be *helping [to] **streamline** bureaucracy* (an adverbial clause providing further information about the aforementioned ***developed infrastructure***, meaning that infrastructure helps get rid of bureaucratic red tape / bottlenecks)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, he does not say *streamlined bureaucracy*. You're mishearing things which is quite understandable since it is somewhat hard to hear. There is no *ed* at the end of *streamline*. And please don't forget that we typically don't use the infinitive marker with the verb *to help* (e.g. *Will you help me move these boxes?*, *James helped move these boxes.*). So, that part should really be:

> all within a developed infrastructure that is run by an independent authority helping streamline bureaucracy

As for the meaning, it's the fact that the developed infrastructure of the Jebel Ali Free zones is run by an independent authority is what helps streamline bureaucracy. Meaning, it (the developed infrastructure of these zones) helps make bureaucracy less of an issue for foreign businessmen and investors who are considering doing business in Dubai.